# What API on Kafka Client would allow one to reset the offset to the last committed one?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using java version of Kafka client versioned 0.10.0.0. In my case auto commit is turned off and we read using KafKaClient.poll(timout) api. We process all the messages and if everything goes well we call the commitSync() explicitly. But in the case of not able to process the messages we want to be able to re read from the last commit. Looking at the API I didn't find anything obvious. Can someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`seek` method](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)). Specifically, since you're auto-committing offsets you know which offset was last committed (or you could - just save that in a variable). If things are failing and you want to back up call `seek` passing the last committed offset.

You could also call the [`committed` method](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#committed(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition)) to ask Kafka what the last saved offset was, but it's so easy to save it yourself you might as well.

It might be a better idea to defer the offset commit until you know things have worked. That's far safer as then it's fine if a machine crashes: if you always consume from the last committed offset you still can guarantee that each message will be seen at least once. If you commit before you know if you processed it you'll never be able to make that guarantee even with a manual seek; what if the machine crashed after you commit the offset but before you notice things didn't succeed.

Comment: Is there no API like reset() to resetToLastCommitted() without having to manage offset? That also means incrementing offsets when reading, managing multiple offsets corresponding to each partition.

Comment: @useful `resetToLastComitted` does not exist but would be equivalent to a call to `comitted` to get the last comitted offset followed by `seek`. It is a little bit of code to write but shouldn't be too hard. You will have to keep track of which partitions your consumer is currently responsible for but Kafka tells you that. I agree that a `resetToLastComitted` would be nice, but since it doesn't exist I think you're stuck with `comitted` and `seek`.

Comment: It appears seek() is per partition and there is no overloaded version that could take multiple partitions along with their offsets. What does it mean if my client is subscribed to multiple partitions and seek on only one of them fails while others succeed. Is there a way to say to seek all the partitions or none if there are failures.

Comment: @useful no, as far as I know there isn't a way to say all or nothing. If a seek doesn't succeed you actually don't know the state - maybe it did succeed on the server but the success message wasn't received. It might be a better idea to defer the offset commit until you know things have worked. That's far safer as then it's fine if a machine crashes: if you always consume from the last committed offset you still can guarantee that each message will be seen at least once. If you commit before you know if you processed it you'll never be able to make that guarantee even with a manual seek.